# How to add items to their respective parent category using coreData ,swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parent

How to add items when i select in dropDown which i can display category list and i can select it but how to link that related item to parent class and save it.

Category Form:-

```
 import CoreData
extension Category {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Category> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Category>(entityName: "Category")
    }
    @NSManaged public var categoryColor: String?
    @NSManaged public var categoryName: String?
    @NSManaged public var items: NSSet?
}
```

Item Class :-

```
extension ItemForm {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ItemForm> {
        return NSFetchRequest<ItemForm>(entityName: "ItemForm")
    }
    @NSManaged public var itemName: String?
    @NSManaged public var price: Int64

    @NSManaged public var parent: Category?
}
```

[image]

Here when i select Category i need to show.

In this itemViewController ,if i save means it should save with respect to their parent class when i'm selecting that category button as drop down it should save in that parent category.

ItemViewController : -

```
 var buttonIndex : Int?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dropdownBtn.setTitle("\(arrCategory[indexPath.row].categoryName!)", for: .normal)
        animated(toogle: false)

        buttonIndex = indexPath.row

    }
      @IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let selectedIndexInPopup = categoryType.title(for: .normal)

            itemSaveData()

            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
func itemSaveData(){

        guard let itemName = itemName.text else { return }
        guard let price = Int64(itemPrice.text!) else { return }

        guard let parentCategorty = buttonIndex else { return }

        let itemList = [
            "itemName": itemName,
            "price": price
            "parentCategory": parentCategorty

            ] as [String : Any]
         if isUpdate{
            editItemData(itemList: itemList, index: indexRow)
            isUpdate = false
        }else{
          saveItemData(itemList: itemList)
        }
}
    func saveItemData(itemList: [String:Any]){
               let item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ItemForm", into: context) as! ItemForm
               item.itemName = itemList["itemName"] as! String
               item.price = itemList["price"] as! Int64
         item.parent = (itemList["parentCategory"] as? Category)
    do{
                   try context.save()
                print("Save Successfully")
               }catch let err{
                   print("college save error :- \(err.localizedDescription)")
               }
           }

    }
```

Comment: The question is quite unclear, the code is a bit hard to read and there's not enough code to establish what you're trying to do. For example, there's a var that represents a single object but it's named like an array `let newArray = Items()` The Realm Items Object is a single object, not an array. I think you may be asking how to add an Items Object to a CategoryForm object but that code is not included - all we see is `self.saveItems(category: newArray)`. Can you update your code and clarify the question?

Comment: yes, i updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to add a new ItemClass Object to an existing CategoryClass.

First, you should be using [primary keys](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys) to identify your items and categories

```
class CategoryClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var category_id = NSUUID().uuidString
   @objc dynamic var categoryName : String = ""
   let items = List<ItemClass>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "category_id"
    }
}
```

same thing with your ItemClass

```
class ItemClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var item_id = NSUUID().uuidString
   @objc dynamic var itemName : String = ""
   @objc dynamic var price : Int64 = 0

   var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: CategoryClass.self, property: "items")
}
```

It looks like you're trying to keep a class var of your categories

```
var categories = CategoryVaraible.categoryArray //not sure what this is
```

but don't do that, do this

```
var categoryResults = Results<CategoryClass>? = nil
```

and use the categoryResults as your dataSource for your tableView.

When the user selects a category and then adds item data, to save it, you'll get the category based on the row selected in the category popup, then create an item and finally add it to the category within a write transaction:

```
func saveItemToCategory() {
   let category = self.categoryResults[selectedIndexInPopup]
   let item = ItemClass()
   item.itemName = some_item_name
   item.price = some_item_price

   try realm.write {
      category.items.append(item)
   }
}
```

Comment: categoryResults[selectedIndexInPopup] ,In selectedIndexInPopup what should i give, category popup is a button how to set in that place.

Comment: I did this one  categoryResults?[categoryType.title(for: .normal)],  It is showing error as "Cannot subscript a value of type 'Results<CategoryForm>' with an argument of type 'String?"

Comment: Your category popup is backed by some kind of dataSource - probably an array or whatever you use to populate it? You need to determine what index is selected in that popup, get the category object from the array `let category = self.categoryResults[selectedIndexInPopup]` and update category accordingly.

Comment: And I am not sure what this is `categoryResults?[categoryType.title(for: .normal)]` as it was not in my answer. This is a string `categoryType.title(for: .normal)` and you cannot access an array element by a string, it needs to be an index `categoryResults[2]` for example

Comment: it is showing error  as .  UnDeclared "SelectedIndexInPopup"

Comment: @ZaheerSk uh. Right. Because you need to get the index of what's selected in the popup and put it there. I don't know how you're popup works or what the backing dataSource is - so you would use code like `let selectedIndexInPopup = yourPopup.selectedIndex` or whatever it may be.